# R web scraping detect highest numerical GADM.org level for an individual country

Tags: r, web-scraping, geospatial

If you browse to gadm.org/country, pick out a country and R Spatial Polygons as the datatype, you get to a download set of the available gadm.org administrative levels for that specific country. The levels available vary by country.

**Is there a way to get the levels (or just the lowest geographic level, highest numeric level) available by country with a function, without actually downloading the files?**

Ideally I would have code that works like this (made up function, not work):

```
getGADMmaxlevel("Nigeria")
[1] 2

getGADMmaxlevel("Haiti")
[1] 4

getGADMmaxlevel("Philippines")
[1] 3
```

**Why I want to do this**: 
I'd like to be able to download and delete the gadm file within a separate function I have created, allowing looping across datasets with a ton of different countries without bogging down disk space (i.e. datasets can get up to 100 or more countries). The idea is to have the same gadm extraction level for all the countries, a highest numerical common level. Thus I need a list of the levels available for download for all countries in the set to determine the highest numerical common level in the set (i.e. the highest numerical gadm layer common to the whole set of countries in a dataset) prior to downloading the file for any individual country. Then I can download and delete the gadm files in line, rather than keeping all at once to determine the highest common levels between them.

**Ideas**:

Dataset lazy loaded: I could download the entire world, and run a check through for na values in the ID_ columns using `grepl` to get just the columns starting in ID_ and `which(is.na())` getting a column of the last available ID_ not all NA's by country. Then I'd need the dataset in the package I'm building (small but tedious) and call it in my function. This is the best way I have thought of so far, but sounds tedious.

Web scrape: gadm.org ui clearly uses cookies to scroll to the download pages (the download link pages are not static links). However, the actual download links are static: i.e. Haiti level 4 is http://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/gadm2.8/rds/HTI_adm4.rds
I could theoretically do a check for if the link works and increase the adm# until it doesn't work, taking the last link that works and extracting the level using substr. This also doesn't sound like fun, and also sounds slow.

Web scrape 2: httr and rvest to get through and save the cookies to get to the download links page, save the download links. That would be pretty complex seeing as there is probably a post request for the R data type and country, etc (ugh!), and slow to get through the three pages before the html links.

Any better ideas out there?

Comment: FYI - Robots.txt on biogeo.ucdavis,edu prohibits accessing /data

Comment: There's already a package in R that scrapes the data, and it states academic use is free. Look at GADMTools on cran

Comment: Also the data links aren't even on the robots.txt site, take a look for yourself and match links (http://gadm.org/robots.txt), no data links forbidden

Comment: The data lives on the biogeo.ucdavis server where /data is forbidden:  take a look:http://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/robots.txt

Comment: I mean, if that's the case the CRAN package is out of bounds too because that's where it's scraping.

Comment: While robots.txt files are important, those URLs will only be used by individuals to download the data (their intended purpose), not to scrape data out of source code. Realistically, the URL is put in robots.txt to stop web crawlers from search engines from downloading all of those enormous files in order to index them (incurring a significant server load), not to stop individuals. To be polite, you could email the maintainer. The solution for this question doesn't actually need to access those URLs, anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rvest can handle POST forms if they're relatively simple, like this one, so you can build a data frame of countries and levels just by scraping each value of the form and the possible level selections on the next page.

First, open an rvest session on the form page and parse the selection values (countries) to iterate over:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

gadm_search <- html_session('http://gadm.org/country')

countries <- gadm_search %>% 
    html_nodes('select[name="cnt"] option') %>% 
    html_attr('value')
```

Prep and store the form (pre-setting the data format selection, though you could do that while iterating, if you prefer):

```r
gadm_form <- gadm_search %>% html_form() %>% .[[1]] %>% set_values(thm = "rds#R data")
```

...and then iterate:

```r
gadm_levels <- countries %>% 
    head() %>%    # plenty for now
    map_df(~{
        Sys.sleep(10);    # per http://gadm.org/robots.txt
        data_frame(country = .x,
                   url = gadm_form %>% 
                       set_values(cnt = .x) %>% 
                       submit_form(gadm_search, .) %>% 
                       html_nodes('b a') %>% 
                       html_attr('href'))
    })
```

Since this gets you URLs, to get the max level, you'll need to parse and summarise a bit, e.g.

```r
gadm_levels %>% 
    mutate(admin_level = parse_number(basename(url))) %>% 
    group_by(country) %>% 
    top_n(1, admin_level) %>% 
    select(-url)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 2
#> # Groups:   country [6]
#>   country                     admin_level
#>   <chr>                             <dbl>
#> 1 AFG_Afghanistan_3                    2.
#> 2 XAD_Akrotiri and Dhekelia_2          1.
#> 3 ALA_Åland_2                          1.
#> 4 ALB_Albania_4                        3.
#> 5 DZA_Algeria_3                        2.
#> 6 ASM_American Samoa_4                 3.
```

Doing this shows that those numbers at the end of the selection seem to be the max level + 1, which means that you can just scrape them and not iterate at all:

```r
gadm_levels2 <- 'http://gadm.org/country' %>% 
    read_html() %>% 
    html_nodes('select[name="cnt"] option') %>% 
    html_attr('value') %>% 
    data_frame(countries = .) %>% 
    separate(countries, c('iso3c', 'country', 'level'), sep = '_', convert = TRUE) %>% 
    mutate(level = level - 1L)

gadm_levels2
#> # A tibble: 254 x 3
#>    iso3c country               level
#>    <chr> <chr>                 <int>
#>  1 AFG   Afghanistan               2
#>  2 XAD   Akrotiri and Dhekelia     1
#>  3 ALA   Åland                     1
#>  4 ALB   Albania                   3
#>  5 DZA   Algeria                   2
#>  6 ASM   American Samoa            3
#>  7 AND   Andorra                   1
#>  8 AGO   Angola                    3
#>  9 AIA   Anguilla                  0
#> 10 ATA   Antarctica                0
#> # ... with 244 more rows
```

You should verify that that data is what it seems, though.

Comment: This is interesting, and thanks for your work on this! This is what I had in mind by my last idea, but it would have taken me far longer to figure out. I'm going to run some tests on speed of loading this directly from web (obviously connection speed will matter a lot) vs. loading it in from a filtered data frame, it's all text so should be tiny packets.

Comment: Loading from the web would require you to add an HTML parser like rvest into your dependencies or write some hacky code; assuming this data doesn't change often, I'd just install it as a dataset in the package (internal, if you like), and then update the data/package whenever a new version of GADM comes out with additional levels.

Comment: yeah I think that's what I'll end up doing and using the rvest code as an updater. GADM claims to be updating in April to 3.0, but the update thing has been changing since predicting 2016 for 3.0 so who knows. In any case this will need just a few modifications (hopefully) for when GADM does update. Thanks again!